# Manager name starting with letter

Tags: sql

In a table with columns EMP_ID, EMP_NAME & MANAGER_ID fetch manager names for all employees whose names start with 'A'. Assume a manager is also an Employee.

### Table: EMP

EMP_ID
EMP_NAME
MGR_ID

Comment: Soooooo what is the problem you are facing?  Show us What have you tried?

Comment: This looks like homework. Nice! Unfortunately, Stack Overflow is not a free homework delivery service, you are expected to make a reasonable and researched attempt and by all means ask for help with a specific problem. Please read [How to ask homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions), the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and see [what is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you don't have a manager's table,  all you have is this employee table. Then,

```
SELECT EMP_NAME
FROM EMP 
WHERE EMP_ID IN (
   SELECT MGR_ID 
   FROM EMP
   WHERE EMP_NAME LIKE "A%"
)
```

should do the task.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need a self join -

```
SELECT E1.EMP_NAME EMPLOYEE_NAME, E2.EMP_NAME MANAGER_NAME
  FROM EMP E1
  LEFT JOIN EMP E2 ON E1.MGR_ID = E2.EMP_ID
 WHERE E1.EMP_NAME LIKE 'A%';
```